# how to add QSpinBox to a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtablewidget, qlineedit, qspinbox

I have a QTableWidget and an object of class product called `p`.
I wanna add items to this table.
I tried the code below but no use.

```
void MainWindow:: add_to_basket (product p){

    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(1);

    QLineEdit *qle=new QLineEdit();
    qle->setText(p.get_name());
    ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(1,1,qle);

    QLineEdit *qle1=new QLineEdit();
    qle1->setText(QString::number(p.get_price()));
    ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(1,2,qle1);

    QSpinBox *qsb=new QSpinBox();
    qsb->setValue(p.get_count());
    ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(1,3,qsb);

}
```

what should I do?

Comment: You are inserting into an empty table, at a location that does not exist. Qt uses 0-based indexing, so trying to insert a row at position 1 in an empty table will fail. Also, are you sure you have set up the table to have enough columns? With your current code, it would need to have 4 columns. I would suggest you store the current rowCount in a const variable `row`, then call `insertRow(row)` and use that same `row` variable for the setCellWidget calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `QTableWidget` should have defined `rowCount` and `columnCount` properties. It can be done either via `QTableWidget` constructor (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#QTableWidget-1) or via appropriate methods (`setRowCounts` and `setColumnCounts`). If it is done already, that's great.
2. `insertRow` inserts an empty row into the table at given position. `ui->tableWidget->insertRow(1)` would insert a new row at position `1` only if you have previously defined `rowCount` and `columnCount` (see point 1).
3. It depends what is your idea here - if you would like to have at least 4 columns (please note that we are counting from 0 and the `QSpinBox` is attempted to be put into third column) and insert new product always at first row, your code with point 1 fullfilled will be work fine. But, if your idea is to add a new row each time new `product` is added, you should rather call `ui->tableWidget->insertRow(tableWidget->rowCount())` and use that value to address appropriate row.

You may also want to have a look here for example how to setup `QTableWidget`: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QTableWidget